# Solving ODE in python

Tags: python, matlab, ode

In MATLAB I am solving this ode as:

```matlab
B = [0 0 -5]'; 
y0 =[0 -5 0 5 0 0]';
f = @(t,y) [y(4:6); (q/m)*cross(y(4:6),B)];
[t,y] = ode45(f,[0 100],y0);
```

I've been reading previous answers about how to solve ODEs in Python and how to fit the MATLAB code to corresponding Python code but, when I try to solve the same ODE as:

```python
f=lambda t,y: np.array([y(np.arange(4,6)),(q/m)*np.cross(y(np.arange(4,6)),B)])
sol =solve_ivp(f, np.array([0 100]), y0)
```

I get an error message(line 454, in solve_ivp solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options))

I also tried:

```python
sol = integrate.odeint(f, np.array([0 100]), y0)
```

without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `y(4:6)` in MATLAB is not `y(np.arange(4,6))` in Python.

   - In MATLAB, `y(4:6)` gets the 4th to 6th elements from array `y`.
   - In Python, that should be `y[3:6]` (square brackets; 3 instead of 4 because Python is 0-indexed; 6 instead of 5 because Python's right bound is non-inclusive).
2. In the MATLAB `f`, the vectors are joined vertically (semicolon), so in Python they should be stacked vertically with `vstack()`.
3. Python lists require commas. In the `sol` line, `[0 100]` needs to be `[0, 100]`.

You probably want something like this:

```
f = lambda t, y: np.vstack([y[3:6], (q/m) * np.cross(y[3:6], B)])
sol = solve_ivp(f, np.array([0, 100]), y0)
```